# Google Apps Script - Error using Text Buttons and URLs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm having an issue with an add-on I'm developing for gmail, I need to create a text button that, when clicked, lets the user go to a certain URL. But when the user clicks it, the following message shows on the console:

```
Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-meBQMySza2c9vxRO9k5EAQ' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.

Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'nonce-meBQMySza2c9vxRO9k5EAQ' 'self' https://apis.google.com https://ssl.gstatic.com https://www.google.com https://www.gstatic.com https://www.google-analytics.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'location')
```

I have tried these two solutions:

Solution 1 - using setOpenLink

```js
  function getLink(link) {
    return CardService.newTextButton()
             .setText("Go to URL")
             .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink()
             .setUrl(link));
  }
```

Solution 2 - using setOnClickOpenLinkAction

```js
  function openLinkCallback(state) {    
    return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
             .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink()
             .setUrl(state.parameters.link))
             .build();
  }

  function getLink(link) {
    var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('openLinkCallback').setParameters({ link: link });

    return CardService.newTextButton()
             .setText("Go to URL")
             .setOnClickOpenLinkAction(action)
  }
```

Which one is the right way to show a link to the user? Is there another thing I might forgot to implement here?

My appsscript.json file is:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Denver",
  "dependencies": {},
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "handleHomePageStart",
        "enabled": true
      },
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#00A82D",
        "secondaryColor": "#00A82D"
      },
      "logoUrl": "https://leprosy.s3.amazonaws.com/outlook-dev/gmail/medium_logo.png",
      "name": "leprosy",
      "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
        "https://www.leprosy.com/",
        "https://leprosy.com/privacy/policy",
        "https://leprosy.com/legal/terms-of-service"
      ],
      "universalActions": [],
      "useLocaleFromApp": true
    },
    "gmail": {
      "contextualTriggers": [
        {
          "unconditional": {},
          "onTriggerFunction": "handleStart"
        }
      ],
      "authorizationCheckFunction": "checkAuth",
      "composeTrigger": {
        "selectActions": [
          {
            "text": "Insert note",
            "runFunction": "handleStartCompose"
          }
        ],
        "draftAccess": "METADATA"
      }
    },
    "calendar": {}
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.storage",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],
  "exceptionLogging": "CLOUD",
  "urlFetchWhitelist": [
    "https://www.leprosy.com/oauth",
    "https://www.leprosy.com/json",
    "https://www.leprosy.com/shard",
    "https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect"
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Seems to be that this issue cannot be reproduced on Firefox, just on Chrome...

Comment: Could you include the content of `appsscript.json`? And how do you set the value of `link` in your `getLink` function?

Comment: The link is just a string, of the form https://www.leprosy.com/client/web/[hash]. I added the appscript.json file to the question.

Comment: Same error here, this used to work. I think something has changed in Chrome...

Comment: Ok, I fixed this issue replacing `setOnClickOpenLinkAction(action)` with this `setOnClickAction(action)`

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you don't specify exactly what link you're trying to open, but make sure that its url prefix is included in "openLinkUrlPrefixes" within your appsscript.json.

So if you wanted to open "https://leprosy.com/a", you should add "https://leprosy.com" to your "openLinkUrlPrefixes". Might help.